# checking login and password in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi i am trying to create a login and password for my app by using SQLite,, every thing is fine but the once the login button is pressed it is not entering in to home page!!!!

please find my code below:

```
-(void)checkindatabase{

    NSArray *dirPath =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir =[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.db"]];


    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"open");
        NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from UserInformation where Username='%@' and Password='%@'",loginName.text,password.text];        //[sql UTF8String];
        //NSLog(@"'%s'",[sql UTF8String]);
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {   if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            { 
                //user name is correct
                //if u want to print in log use below code  
                homepage *hvc = [[homepage alloc]initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
                hvc.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
                [self presentModalViewController:hvc animated: YES];

            }
            else {   
                UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed!!!"
                                                                message:@"Check your PId and Password" delegate:nil 
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

                }}            

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
-(IBAction)homePage: (id)sender
{
    [self checkindatabase];

}
```

Comment: Just make that `checkindatabase` method returns a bool whether the credentials are valid or not. Check the bool value and then show the UIAlertView or your home view depend on that.

Comment: Hi @Aadhira,@Dshan can you please show BOOL Method in form of Code, because my code is showing error if i am doing it

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code, as you asked.

```
-(BOOL)checkindatabase
{
    NSArray *dirPath =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir =[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.db"]];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"open");
        NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from UserInformation where Username='%@' and Password='%@'",loginName.text,password.text];        //[sql UTF8String];
        //NSLog(@"'%s'",[sql UTF8String]);
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {   if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            { 
                //user name is correct
                //if u want to print in log use below code  
                return YES;
            }
        }            
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return NO;
}

-(IBAction)homePage: (id)sender
{
    if( [self checkindatabase] )
    {
        homepage *hvc = [[homepage alloc]initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
        hvc.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:hvc animated: YES];
        [hvc release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed!!!"
                                                        message:@"Check your PId and Password" delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}
```

Comment: Aadhira: if i follow your code it is showing invaid for even correct login's!!!!!!!! if i follow Dshah's code the page is opening for even unknown password and id's, !!!!!!!!

Comment: Just put breakpoints and check step by step where the condition is failing.

Comment: if i delete " return NO; " the login button is working, But it is accepting any names and passwords, if i keep " return NO; " continuously showing Login failed!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Aadhira...

Make `checkindatabase` with return type `BOOL` and return `TRUE` if Login successful and `FALSE` otherwise.

Then on the basis of `BOOL` value navigate to Home Page.

you cannot let other function to navigate the view, while performing `IBAction` method.

**EDIT :**

I am not looking to your database code.. i have simply shown you way how to use the BOOL return values....  Also mention errors if any you faced.

```
-(BOOL)checkindatabase{

    NSArray *dirPath =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir =[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.db"]];


    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"open");
        NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from UserInformation where Username='%@' and Password='%@'",loginName.text,password.text];        //[sql UTF8String];
        //NSLog(@"'%s'",[sql UTF8String]);
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {   if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            { 
                //user name is correct
                //if u want to print in log use below code  
                flag = YES;

            }
            else {   
                UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed!!!"
                                                                message:@"Check your PId and Password" delegate:nil 
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
                flag = NO;

                }}            

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return flag;
}
-(IBAction)homePage: (id)sender
{
   BOOL newFlag = [self checkindatabase];
   if(newFlag)
   {
        homepage *hvc = [[homepage alloc]initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil]
        hvc.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:hvc animated: YES];
   }
}
```

Comment: can you please show BOOL Method in form of Code, because my code is showing error if i am doing it

Comment: I have updated my answer... please see it.... also keep accepting answers for better response from SO users... njoy Coding... :)

Comment: HI DShah: what is flag here??

Comment: DShah: if i follow your code the page is opening for even unknown password and id's, if i follow Aadira code it is showing invaid for even correct login's!!!!!!!!

Comment: here you should declare flag in .h file as @property. Also for login query its your logic mistake so firstly clear your logic then go for navigation. And you have already accepted answer....???